# "System Error. Code: 87" when calling ConvertStringSidToSid()

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-7, delphi-xe3

I must set prmissions on some folder for "Everyone" user group, so i need SID for this group. When I calling `ConvertStringSidToSid()` I get error `"System Error. Code: 87 - Parameter is incorrect"`. Why? What is wrong with my code?

```
...
function ConvertStringSidToSid(StringSid: LPCTSTR; Sid: PSID): BOOL; stdcall;
  external Advapi32 name 'ConvertStringSidToSidW';
...
var
  Sid: PSID;
...
  Sid := Nil;
  ConvertStringSidToSid(LPCTSTR('S-1-1-0'), Sid);
...
```

TIA Branko

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Sid` parameter is output. Add the `out` keyword to it in your function prototype. Also, it's not safe to use `LPCTSTR` with Unicode version of the function (the one with `W` postfix). Once you'd migrate this code to non-Unicode Delphi, you will fail with its call, because `LPCTSTR` become `PAnsiChar` on non-Unicode Delphi and you'd call the Unicode function. Rather use directly `PWideChar` instead:

```
function ConvertStringSidToSid(StringSid: PWideChar; out Sid: PSID): BOOL; stdcall;
  external Advapi32 name 'ConvertStringSidToSidW';
```